# Using nonessential clauses in a list of items

Tags: commas

In this sentence, would you put a comma after daughter, Harper, and dog?

Fun for me includes spending time with my family, watching my daughter Harper grow, playing with my dog Emma, golfing, cooking, watching Tennessee Vol sporting events, listening to old music, and perfecting dad jokes.

Comment: The only problem there is the comma between "music" and  "and" that should be removed. Avoid adding commas after "daughter", "Harper", and "dog".

Comment: That Oxford comma is considered optional.

Answer (score 0):

> Fun for me includes spending time with my family, watching my daughter Harper grow, playing with my dog Emma, golfing, cooking, watching Tennessee Vol sporting events, listening to old music, and perfecting dad jokes.

This sentence is already clear, and there is no need to add **bracketing commas** for the appositives Harper and Emma.

Such additions are not wrong but would clutter the sentence, which already has several **listing commas**, and affect the smooth flow.

Comment: You could replace the listing commas with semicolons if you really needed/wanted bracketing commas, but I agree the current arrangement is better.